# Calculating age from dataframe (dob -y/m/d)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to add a column "Age" to my data

```
number of purchased hours(mins) dob Y   dob M   dob D
0   7200    2010.0  10.0    12.0
1   7320    2010.0  6.0 2.0
2   5400    2011.0  6.0 18.0
3   9180    2009.0  10.0    18.0
4   3102    2007.0  7.0 30.0
5   5400    2011.0  4.0 6.0
6   9000    2009.0  8.0 5.0
7   6000    2004.0  2.0 7.0
8   6000    2007.0  8.0 17.0
9   6000    2013.0  5.0 5.0
10  12000   2012.0  9.0 27.0
11  12000   2004.0  11.0    25.0
12  6000    2009.0  11.0    20.0
```

I've tried this code, but not sure what went wrong

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df['Age'] = datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df[['dob D','dob M','dob Y']])
```

Below is the error that popped up

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with 3 columns it working only with renamed columns names:

```
d = {'dob Y':'year', 'dob M':'month', 'dob D':'day'}
df['Age'] = (pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d') - 
               pd.to_datetime(df[['dob D','dob M','dob Y']].rename(columns=d)))

print (df)
    number of purchased hours(mins)   dob Y  dob M  dob D       Age
0                              7200  2010.0   10.0   12.0 3380 days
1                              7320  2010.0    6.0    2.0 3512 days
2                              5400  2011.0    6.0   18.0 3131 days
3                              9180  2009.0   10.0   18.0 3739 days
4                              3102  2007.0    7.0   30.0 4550 days
5                              5400  2011.0    4.0    6.0 3204 days
6                              9000  2009.0    8.0    5.0 3813 days
7                              6000  2004.0    2.0    7.0 5819 days
8                              6000  2007.0    8.0   17.0 4532 days
9                              6000  2013.0    5.0    5.0 2444 days
10                            12000  2012.0    9.0   27.0 2664 days
11                            12000  2004.0   11.0   25.0 5527 days
12                             6000  2009.0   11.0   20.0 3706 days
```

If want convert timedeltas to days:

```
d = {'dob Y':'year', 'dob M':'month', 'dob D':'day'}
df['Age'] = ((pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d') - 
               pd.to_datetime(df[['dob D','dob M','dob Y']].rename(columns=d)))
               .dt.days)

print (df)
    number of purchased hours(mins)   dob Y  dob M  dob D   Age
0                              7200  2010.0   10.0   12.0  3380
1                              7320  2010.0    6.0    2.0  3512
2                              5400  2011.0    6.0   18.0  3131
3                              9180  2009.0   10.0   18.0  3739
4                              3102  2007.0    7.0   30.0  4550
5                              5400  2011.0    4.0    6.0  3204
6                              9000  2009.0    8.0    5.0  3813
7                              6000  2004.0    2.0    7.0  5819
8                              6000  2007.0    8.0   17.0  4532
9                              6000  2013.0    5.0    5.0  2444
10                            12000  2012.0    9.0   27.0  2664
11                            12000  2004.0   11.0   25.0  5527
12                             6000  2009.0   11.0   20.0  3706
```